# Are the names of files uploaded to an HTML multi-file upload input guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: html, django, forms, file

Let's say I have a form with a multi-file upload input like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="files">Select files:</label>
  <input type="file" id="docs" name="docs" multiple><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have a Django backend that is parsing this upload:

```
def view(request):
    files = request.FILES.getlist("docs")
    file_names = [f.name for f in files]
    if len(file_names) != len(set(file_names)):
        raise Exception("Duplicate file names")
```

Assuming the files are actually uploaded in a mainstream browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari, Opera), are the names for the files uploaded in this input guaranteed to be unique?  I.e. is there any way for the exception in the backend to get raised?

Most browsers' implementation of the multi-file upload give the user the ability to pick files from a single directory.  As far as I know, all operating systems don't allow for files with the same name in the same directory.  But is there something I'm missing (such as browsers stripping or converting characters in the file name that can cause a collision)?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to save the files to disk? Whether or not there is a risk of collisions depend on how you have implemented that.

Comment: @solarissmoke I'm not asking about collisions in saving the files.  I know that there is potential for collisions there because the same file could be uploaded twice across two submissions of the form.  I'm asking about collisions in the batch of uploaded files.